# Prepare a message with full indexation payload. My own Iota client. How to do POW on the client

Tags: iri-legacy-api, pow

I decided to do my own Iota Client Library on [Qt](https://www.qt.io/), until the C one from the foundation is out (because Rust is killing me).

I have check [HTTP REST API documentation](https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rufsam/protocol-rfcs/master/text/0026-rest-api/rest-api.yaml). I have implemented a minimal message( only with the "payload" key) and is working. But when i try to send many big payloads(less than 31k) on the mainnet i get **Gateway timeout error** (I think is error 503).

I am trying to send a full indexation message now.   So, my question is how i can get the missing fields on the post request.

Meaning :

"**networkId:**"  ?

"**parentMessageIds:**" ?(I will try with /api/v1/tips)

"**nonce:**" ?

More importantly how to do the POW on the device(I think is related with the **nonce** parameter). I do not find any literature about this. And if you know about why i am getting the **Gateway timeout error** on the mainnet  and not on the devnet load balanced endpoints.

If you can give me any reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following RFCs

- [Message](https://github.com/GalRogozinski/protocol-rfcs/blob/message/text/0017-message/0017-message.md)
- [Message PoW](https://github.com/Wollac/protocol-rfcs/blob/message-pow/text/0024-message-pow/0024-message-pow.md)

The client can simply sign a transaction then ask a node doing the PoW job. the procedure is something like: `create and sign message -> get tips -> send the message`, see https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.c/blob/dev/src/client/api/v1/send_message.c#L254

I think Qt can use c client lib - [iota.c](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.c). API Reference: https://iota-c-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/client.html